# Unable to read mapping file, Gradle Task Execution Exception [Android]

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been getting this weird error from Gradle while building the release build. I have different flavors set up in my project i.e QC, Staging, Live. Building a release build on QC and Live flavor works perfectly, but whenever I try to create a release build via Staging Flavor, it throws this gradle exception.

```
:app:retraceStagingReleaseMainDexClassList FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:retraceStagingReleaseMainDexClassList'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to read mapping file.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.multidex.RetraceMainDexList.createDict(RetraceMainDexList.groovy:113)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.multidex.RetraceMainDexList$createDict.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.multidex.RetraceMainDexList.retrace(RetraceMainDexList.groovy:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
```

I have enabled Multidex and proguard on my Android project. This error is being thrown ever since I have upgraded compile and build SDK to Android M. I have followed all the instructions from Google Docs about upgrading the project. This is the snippet of the build.gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 15091000
        versionName "5.0.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4G"

    }

    productFlavors {
        qc {
            applicationId = "com.example.qc"
            versionName "5.0.2.8"
            buildConfigField  "int", "appMode", "1"
        }
        dev {
            applicationId = "com.example.dev"
            versionName "5.0.2.8"
            buildConfigField  "int", "appMode", "2"
        }
        staging {
            applicationId = "com.example.staging"
            versionName "5.0.2.8"
            buildConfigField  "int", "appMode", "4"
        }
        prod {
            applicationId = "com.example"
            versionName "5.0.2.8"
            buildConfigField  "int", "appMode", "5"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
//            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

I have researched a lot about this issue on Stackoverflow and Google forum. They said, it may be due to 64k method limit reached, and for that, I'm now using MultiDex support that builds multiple dex files for project with method count greater than 64k. But I guess, it doesn't have anything to do with the Staging Build throwing this error, while other flavors are generating the release build without any errors.

I don't see any difference in build.gradle file for product flavors. Anyone has ever happened to come across this kind of issue? Please help!

Comment: Are you using NewRelic?

Comment: @jgonza73 Yes. I'm using New Relics. Is it causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with ProGuard and MultiDex. I have figured out that NewRelic plugin (v1.3.+) appends a line to mapping.txt such as "**# NR_BUILD_ID: XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX**" and I think this is the problem.

As you can see in Android gradle googlesource, groovy file [RetraceMainDexList](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/9fba95348ef762fd9a7c82ac332d119684a74bcb/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/multidex/RetraceMainDexList.groovy) (line 105), it will raise a RuntimeException("unable to read mapping file.") if found a line in mapping.txt starting with no-space and doesn't contain " -> " string. So, the line NR appends to **mapping.txt** raise this Exception and make :*retraceMainDexClassList* task crash.

If you delete # NR_BUILD_ID line, application runs fine.

I have sent this issue to NewRelic support and they confirmed my findings. They told me the issue was sent to developers for handle this going forward.

I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much @jgonza73. I have removed NewRelics from the project, and it's not throwing this exception anymore.